# Axon 4 - JpaEventStorageEngine protected constructor

Tags: spring-boot, axon

When trying to configure the Upcaster in Axon 4 based on the documentation available at : [Axon 4 Framework Versioning Events](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/operations-guide/production-considerations/versioning-events#event-upcasting)

I am getting the error: JpaEventStorageEngine() has protected access

```
    @Bean
    public JpaEventStorageEngine eventStorageEngine(
            Serializer serializer,
            DataSource dataSource,
            SingleEventUpcaster myUpcaster,
            EntityManagerProvider entityManagerProvider,
            PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new JpaEventStorageEngine(serializer,
                myUpcaster::upcast,
                dataSource,
                entityManagerProvider,
                transactionManager);
    }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can help you with this.

You have, sadly, found an issue with the reference guide just now.
As off Axon 4, all the main infrastructure components no longer get created through a constructor, but through a [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Thus, the right approach to create it would be:

```
@Bean
public JpaEventStorageEngine eventStorageEngine(Serializer eventSerializer,
                                                Serializer snapshotSerializer,
                                                DataSource dataSource,
                                                SingleEventUpcaster myUpcaster,
                                                EntityManagerProvider entityManagerProvider,
                                                TransactionManager transactionManager) throws SQLException {
    return JpaEventStorageEngine.builder()
                                .eventSerializer(eventSerializer)
                                .snapshotSerializer(snapshotSerializer)
                                .dataSource(dataSource)
                                .entityManagerProvider(entityManagerProvider)
                                .transactionManager(transactionManager)
                                .upcasterChain(myUpcaster)
                                .build();
}
```

I've just adjusted the Reference Guide to reflect this accordingly; I'm terribly sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks so much for the prompt response! Nothing sad about it :) We iterate until it is right.